# How do I set up a WebSphere JMS topic across two clusters?

Tags: jms, websphere, jms-topic

In WAS 9.0.5, I have a single cell of 2 clusters with 2 servers in each. I'd like to have a JMS topic that can be subscribed to by all 4 servers. Currently, I have a separate bus, topic connection factory and activation spec in both clusters, but a message published in one cluster is not consumed in the other cluster.

Should I have a cell level bus with each of the 4 servers as bus members? Or add the 2 clusters as bus members? What's the correct way to set up a topic across multiple clusters?

Answer (score 1):

You should configure a single bus for the cell. That would enable the behaviour you are interested in. Topics are scoped by the bus not the cell, so to make your current topology work you would need to set up an inter-bus link, but given you are all in the same cell that would be needlessly complex for your scenario.

There is really little reason to have more than one bus in a cell.